# find all functions (including private) in a package

Tags: r

I know `ls("package:grid")` and `find.funs("package:grid")` in `mvbutils` but apparently neither of them can find non-exported functions and methods that are only accessible internally or with `:::` or `getAnywhere`.

I've had to source the files in the `/R` directory of the source package and use `ls()` on a clean global environment, but there must be a better way, no?

Comment: ``get`` and ``getFromNamespace`` seem to call to an ``.internal``, and they need to know a particular name, which doesn't help much.  That your read?

Comment: What is a particular symbol in ``package:grid`` that you don't see listed in ``ls(package:grid)`` but expect to?

Comment: 481 of them, according to the solutions below `setdiff(unclass(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("grid"), all = T)), ls('package:grid'))`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can use `asNamespace`:

```
> methods(cbind)
[1] cbind.data.frame cbind.grobGrid   cbind.ts*       

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
> r <- unclass(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("stats"), all = T))
> r[grep("cbind.ts", r)]
[1] ".cbind.ts" "cbind.ts"
```

`cbind.ts` in `stats` package is invisible but can find in `envir = asNamespace("stats")`.

Comment: Neat, thanks. Both answers work fine, but since only one can be accepted I'll opt for the one-liner.

Comment: `ls(asNamespace("stats"))` can also give what you want, in a vector.

Answer (score 27):

This appears to be something of a [perennial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114355/show-names-of-everything-in-a-package/12115495#12115495) here.

If it's this one-liners you're after then this should be a contender (credit @Joshua):

```
ls(getNamespace("grid"), all.names=TRUE)
```

(Link is to a question that was asked *after* the above, but closely related).

As `grid` is a base package and I haven't yet moved up to *R 3...* I'm getting 756 functions with Version 2.15.1. vs. 503 from the `unclass` solution.

Comment: `707` vs `778` in recent R; most of the setdiff seems to be internal C routines (`grid:::L_textBounds`) or constants (`grid:::Mb`).

Comment: Thanks. To have only private functions : `setdiff( ls(getNamespace("ThePackage"), all.names=TRUE), ls("package:ThePackage", all.names=TRUE))`