# Show names of everything in a package

Tags: r, r-package

Is there an easy way to list everything in a package from within R?
For example, if I type `foreach:::` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, I can see everything that's there.
How else can I get those names of objects?

Note, `ls("package:foreach", all.names=TRUE)` does not show things like `.foreachGlobals`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ls("package:foreach", all.names=TRUE)` only shows what's attached to the search path, which only includes the objects exported from the namespace.  Use `ls` on the results of `getNamespace` instead:

```
ls(getNamespace("foreach"), all.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: This worked for some packages, but not for `ls(getNamespace("datasets"), all.names=TRUE)` (rather than listing the datasets that package provides, it returned `[1] ".__NAMESPACE__."      ".__S3MethodsTable__." ".packageName"`. Any idea why it doesn't seem to work for that package?

Comment: @stevec probably because `datasets` doesn't contain any functions/objects, only data. You can see the data included in a package using `data(package = "datasets")`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I tried that, and it is imprecise. For example, see the third item in the list `as.data.frame(data(package = "datasets")[[3]])$Item`. It gives `BJsales.lead (BJsales)`, but the actual dataset is `BJsales.lead`. Someone gave a way to get the data from the datasets package [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68694583/5783745), but it uses a regex tailored for the datasets package (rather than a general solution)

Answer (score 7):

A [utility that I've been using](https://github.com/raredd/rawr/blob/master/R/utils.R#L273:L302) which I find useful for this (and also gives some other helpful things) such as:

```
ls(get('.__NAMESPACE__.', envir = asNamespace('ggplot2', base.OK = FALSE),
       inherits = FALSE))
[1] "dynlibs"   "exports"   "imports"   "lazydata"  "path"      "S3methods" "spec"
```

to access all exported and internal variables in the NAMESPACE, ie,

`ggplot2:::`

```
lsp(ggplot2)

# [1] ".__C__Scales"                     ".__global__"                     
# [3] ".__NAMESPACE__."                  ".__S3MethodsTable__."            
# [5] ".all_aesthetics"                  ".base_to_ggplot"                 
# [7] ".element_tree"                    ".onAttach"                       
# [9] ".packageName"                     ".plot_store" 
# ...
```

to access only exported, ie,

`ggplot2::`

```
lsp(ggplot2, 'exports')

# $exports
# [1] "%+%"                       "%+replace%"               
# [3] "aes"                       "aes_all"                  
# [5] "aes_auto"                  "aes_q"                    
# [7] "aes_string"                "annotate"                 
# [9] "annotation_custom"         "annotation_logticks"    
# ...
```

for the library path

```
lsp('ggplot2', 'path')

# $path
# [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/ggplot2"
```

for data included in packages

```
lsp('ggplot2', 'lazydata')

# $lazydata
# [1] "diamonds"     "economics"    "midwest"      "movies"       "mpg"         
# [6] "msleep"       "presidential" "seals"
```

for S3 methods

```
lsp('ggplot2', 'S3methods')

# $S3methods
# [,1]                         [,2]                       [,3]                              
# [1,] "+"                     "gg"                       "+.gg"                            
# [2,] "["                     "uneval"                   "[.uneval"                        
# [3,] "as.character"          "uneval"                   "as.character.uneval"             
# [4,] "autoplot"              "default"                  "autoplot.default"                
# [5,] "coord_aspect"          "default"                  "coord_aspect.default"            
# [6,] "coord_aspect"          "fixed"                    "coord_aspect.fixed"              
# [7,] "coord_aspect"          "map"                      "coord_aspect.map"                
# [8,] "coord_aspect"          "polar"                    "coord_aspect.polar"              
# [9,] "coord_aspect"          "quickmap"                 "coord_aspect.quickmap" 
# ...
```

to see everything

```
lsp('ggplot2')

# pages and pages
```

code:

```
lsp <- function(package, what, pattern) {
  if (!is.character(substitute(package)))
    package <- deparse(substitute(package))
  ns <- asNamespace(package)
  if (missing(pattern))
    pattern <- '.*'

  ## base package does not have NAMESPACE
  if (isBaseNamespace(ns)) {
    res <- ls(.BaseNamespaceEnv, all.names = TRUE)
    return(res[grep(pattern, res, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)])
  } else {
    ## for non base packages
    if (exists('.__NAMESPACE__.', envir = ns, inherits = FALSE)) {
      wh <- get('.__NAMESPACE__.', inherits = FALSE,
                envir = asNamespace(package, base.OK = FALSE))
      what <- if (missing(what)) 'all'
      else if ('?' %in% what) return(ls(wh)) 
      else ls(wh)[pmatch(what[1], ls(wh))]
      if (!is.null(what) && !any(what %in% c('all', ls(wh))))
        stop('\'what\' should be one of ',
             paste0(shQuote(ls(wh)), collapse = ', '),
             ', or \'all\'', domain = NA)
      res <- sapply(ls(wh), function(x) getNamespaceInfo(ns, x))
      res <- rapply(res, ls, classes = 'environment',
                    how = 'replace', all.names = TRUE)
      if (is.null(what))
        return(res[grep(pattern, res, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)])
      if (what %in% 'all') {
        res <- ls(getNamespace(package), all.names = TRUE)
        return(res[grep(pattern, res, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)])
      }
      if (any(what %in% ls(wh))) {
        res <- res[[what]]
        return(res[grep(pattern, res, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)])
      }
    } else stop(sprintf('no NAMESPACE file found for package %s', package))
  }
}
```

I also like it because it shows how useful `rapply` can be :}

Answer (score 1):

Revolution R Enterprise (free for Academic use) is an editor/debugger/GUI for R which has an 'Object Browser' window open on startup by default. Clicking on a package allows you to see all of its contents including classes and environments. I find this quite helpful.

Comment: Seems like an expensive solution if you're not in academia. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I recently created a script that works well for getting this information. It will take a vector of package names get the following information for every function within each package. The package name, the function name, the str() for the function, and the description text from the help file for each function. Code is below in case if anyone is interested.

```
available.packages <- installed.packages()
suppressMessages(if(!"XML" %in% available.packages) install.packages("XML",repos = "https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/"))
library(XML)

# Function to get data from help console
help_console <- function(topic, format=c("text", "html", "latex", "Rd"),
                         lines=NULL, before=NULL, after=NULL, pkg) {  
  format=match.arg(format)
  if (!is.character(topic)) topic <- deparse(substitute(topic))

  helpfile <- tryCatch({
    helpfile <- utils:::.getHelpFile(help(topic, package = as.character(pkg)))
  }, error = function(err) {
    helpfile <- NA
  }) 

  if(!is.na(helpfile[1]))
    {hs <- capture.output(switch(format, 
                                 text=tools:::Rd2txt(helpfile),
                                 html=tools:::Rd2HTML(helpfile),
                                 latex=tools:::Rd2latex(helpfile),
                                 Rd=tools:::prepare_Rd(helpfile)))

     if(!is.null(lines)) hs <- hs[lines]
     hs <- c(before, hs, after)
     html <- paste(hs, sep="\n", collapse = "")
  } else{
    html <- NA
  }

  return(html)
}

# Function to retrieve information on functions within a package
get.funcs <- function(pkg){
  if(pkg %in% available.packages){
    print(pkg)
    require(pkg, character.only = TRUE)

    df <- as.data.frame(as.vector(lsf.str(paste0("package:", pkg))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(df) <- "function.name"

    df$usage <- sapply(df$function.name, function(x) capture.output(str(get(x)))[1])
    df$package <- pkg

    df$description <- mapply(function(x,y) {
                             html <- help_console(x, "html", lines = 1:25, before = "", after = "", pkg = y)
                             if(!is.na(html)){
                               doc <- htmlParse(html, asText = TRUE)
                               plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)[1]
                             } else{
                               plain.text <- NA
                             }
                             },
                             df$function.name,
                             df$package)

    return(df[,c("package","function.name","usage","description")])
  } else{
    print(paste(pkg, "- has not been installed and cannot be processed!"))
    return(NULL)
  }
}


# Create a vector of packages to process
packages <- c("base","dplyr","lubridate","plyr","readr","readxl","reshape2","RODBC","stringr","tidyr","XLConnect","xlsx","XML","zoo")

# Create a list of dataframes containing package information
ldf <- lapply(packages, get.funcs)

# Combine all dataframes in the list to a single dataframe
df <- do.call(rbind, ldf)
```