# List of functions of a package

Tags: r

Is there an easy, friendly way  to list all functions of a package without downloading those huge PDFs (package references)? I need this for getting me familiar with the package, finding proper functions etc.

I tried `?rjags` but it doesn't do what I expected.

Comment: Related: [Show names of everything in a package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114355/show-names-of-everything-in-a-package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I've been able to find for this is:

```
help(,"rjags")
```

The first parameter specifies the searched thing, second one specifies the package. By keeping only the second one, I hope to get all help pages that relate to that package. This is equivalent of

```
help(package = "rjags")
```

This might not work in general though, as in `?help` the functionality of omitting the first parameter is described as

> topic is not optional: if it is omitted R will give
>
> - If a package is specified, (text or, in interactive use only, HTML)    information on the package, including hints/links to suitable help
>     topics.

Comment: you can also do `library(help = rjags)`

Comment: also `browseVignettes('rjags')` is useful if there are vignettes in the package

Comment: wow, the `library` one is good, thanks @rawr!

Answer (score 11):

Load the package (for example the `car`package). Then use `ls()`

```
ls("package:car")
```

Comment: +1 good tip, thanks! But I am sorry but I didn't say that I need it for help purposes, thus `help(,"rjags")` gives more digestable result for me. I have updated the question.

Comment: I prefer `lsf.str`, which gives the function names *and* their arguments; but, also a little more clutter on the screen.  It's used the same way: `lsf.str("package:car")`