# R: passing a variable to library, ls and?

Tags: r

I am trying to pass a variable to install.package,library, ls and ?
Passing a variable to install.package works fine, but I get an error for the others.

```
name1 <- as.character("dplyr")
install.packages(name1)
library(name1)
ls(name1)
?name1
```

I would be greatfull for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `ls(eval(parse(text=name1)))` or perhaps `ls(get(name1))`. Both should work

Comment: Please read the documentation for the functions in question. All three answers are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the three issues, `library(name1)`, can be resolved with the option  `character.only = TRUE`:

```
library(name1, character.only = TRUE)
```

To list all the objects in the library with the name stored in `name1`, try

```
ls(paste0("package:",name1))
```

or

```
ls(getNamespace(name1))
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114355/show-names-of-everything-in-a-package/) for a discussion on the difference between these two commands, including further options to show hidden objects).

Concerning the third point,  `?`, I have no solution to offer other than using `help(name1)` instead, as suggested also by @PierreLafortune.

Comment: If they have a special fetish for question marks you can also use `'?'(name1) `

Comment: I can't get ls(eval(name1)) to list all the functions in the package.

Comment: @adam.888 I don't think that you would obtain the desired result if you typed in the name of the package directly, instead of using the variable `name1`. I edited the answer to show a possibility to list all the objects in the package. Hope this helps.