# Get a list of the all the names of the objects in the datasets R package?

Tags: r

How can I get a list of the exact names of the objects in the [datasets](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) package?

I found many of them here:

```
data_package = data(package="datasets")
datasets <- as.data.frame(data_package[[3]])$Item
datasets

#   [1] "AirPassengers"          "BJsales"                "BJsales.lead (BJsales)" "BOD"                    "CO2"                    "ChickWeight"           
#   [7] "DNase"                  "EuStockMarkets"         "Formaldehyde"           "HairEyeColor"           "Harman23.cor"           "Harman74.cor"          
#  [13] "Indometh"               "InsectSprays"           "JohnsonJohnson"         "LakeHuron"              "LifeCycleSavings"       "Loblolly"              
#  [19] "Nile"                   "Orange"                 "OrchardSprays"          "PlantGrowth"            "Puromycin"              "Seatbelts"             
#  [25] "Theoph"                 "Titanic"                "ToothGrowth"            "UCBAdmissions"          "UKDriverDeaths"         "UKgas"                 
#  [31] "USAccDeaths"            "USArrests"              "USJudgeRatings"         "USPersonalExpenditure"  "UScitiesD"              "VADeaths"              
#  [37] "WWWusage"               "WorldPhones"            "ability.cov"            "airmiles"               "airquality"             "anscombe"              
#  [43] "attenu"                 "attitude"               "austres"                "beaver1 (beavers)"      "beaver2 (beavers)"      "cars"                  
#  [49] "chickwts"               "co2"                    "crimtab"                "discoveries"            "esoph"                  "euro"                  
#  [55] "euro.cross (euro)"      "eurodist"               "faithful"               "fdeaths (UKLungDeaths)" "freeny"                 "freeny.x (freeny)"     
#  [61] "freeny.y (freeny)"      "infert"                 "iris"                   "iris3"                  "islands"                "ldeaths (UKLungDeaths)"
#  [67] "lh"                     "longley"                "lynx"                   "mdeaths (UKLungDeaths)" "morley"                 "mtcars"                
#  [73] "nhtemp"                 "nottem"                 "npk"                    "occupationalStatus"     "precip"                 "presidents"            
#  [79] "pressure"               "quakes"                 "randu"                  "rivers"                 "rock"                   "sleep"                 
#  [85] "stack.loss (stackloss)" "stack.x (stackloss)"    "stackloss"              "state.abb (state)"      "state.area (state)"     "state.center (state)"  
#  [91] "state.division (state)" "state.name (state)"     "state.region (state)"   "state.x77 (state)"      "sunspot.month"          "sunspot.year"          
#  [97] "sunspots"               "swiss"                  "treering"               "trees"                  "uspop"                  "volcano"               
# [103] "warpbreaks"             "women"
```

So something like this would iterate through each one

```
for(i in 1:length(datasets)) {
  print(get(datasets[i]))
  cat("\n\n")
}
```

It works for the first two datasets (`AirPassengers` and `BJsales`), but it fails on `BJsales.lead (BJsales)` since it should be referred to as `datasets::BJsales.lead`.

I guess I could use string split or similar to discard anything from a space onwards, but I wonder is there any neater way of obtaining a list of all the objects in the `dataset` package?

#### Notes

- In addition to the above, I also tried [listing everything in the `datasets` namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115495/5783745) but it gave a weird result:

```
ls(getNamespace("datasets"), all.names=TRUE)
# [1] ".__NAMESPACE__."      ".__S3MethodsTable__." ".packageName"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a note on the `?data` help page that states

> Where the datasets have a different name from the argument that should be used to retrieve them the index will have an entry like `beaver1 (beavers)` which tells us that dataset `beaver1` can be retrieved by the call `data(beavers)`.

So the actual object name is the thing before the parentheses at the end. Since that value is returned as just a string, that's something you'll need to remove yourself unfortunately. But you can do that with a `gsub`

```
datanames <- data(package="datasets")$results[,"Item"]
objnames <- gsub("\\s+\\(.*\\)","", datanames)

for(ds in objnames) {
  print(get(ds))
  cat("\n\n")
}
```