# Is there a command in R to view all the functions present in a package?

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is a command, using which one can view all the functions that are built into an R package.

For example, let's say I loaded a package into environment:

```
require(dplyr)
```

Now, I would like to get a list of all the functions present in the `dplyr` package.

Is there any way to get such a list?

Comment: you can try `library(help="dplyr" )`, but it will show only the user defined functions, for example the one which do not begin with a point

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Just tried out the command you gave. That was what I was looking for. Very helpful... Thank you so much.

Comment: See also ["find all functions (including private) in a package"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696158/find-all-functions-including-private-in-a-package/8696442#8696442)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use `lsf.str`.

For instance:

```
lsf.str("package:dplyr")
```

To list all objects in the package use `ls`

```
ls("package:dplyr")
```

Note that the package must be attached.

To see the list of currently loaded packages use

```
search()
```

---

Alternatively calling the help would also do, even if the package is not attached:

```
help(package = dplyr)
```

Finally, you can use RStudio which provides an autocomplete function. So, for instance, typing `dplyr::` in the console or while editing a file will result in a popup list of all `dplyr` functions/objects.

Comment: Oh that final part `dplyr::` (and ctrl+spacebar for the autocomplete list) was completely new to me.. thanks again.

Comment: @KrishnaKanth the newer (beta) versions of RStudio have automatic autocomplete (without having to press CTRL+SPACE) as well as other goodness such as debugging and more!