# List all functions as a dataframe

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract all default functions in R. For example. in the below picture, can we extract all these summary functions in a dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Do you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392542/is-there-a-command-in-r-to-view-all-the-functions-present-in-a-package ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `methods` to list all the methods off summary

```
methods('summary')
#[1] summary.aov                    summary.aovlist*               summary.aspell*                summary.check_packages_in_dir*
#[5] summary.connection             summary.data.frame             summary.Date                   summary.default               
#[9] summary.ecdf*                  summary.factor                 summary.glm                    summary.infl*                 
#[13] summary.lm                     summary.loess*                 summary.manova                 summary.matrix                
#[17] summary.mlm*                   summary.nls*                   summary.packageStatus*         summary.POSIXct               
#[21] summary.POSIXlt                summary.ppr*                   summary.prcomp*                summary.princomp*             
#[25] summary.proc_time              summary.rlang_error*           summary.rlang_trace*           summary.srcfile               
#[29] summary.srcref                 summary.stepfun                summary.stl*                   summary.table                 
#[33] summary.tukeysmooth*           summary.vctrs_sclr*            summary.vctrs_vctr*            summary.warnings
```

It is a `vector`, so if we need a `data.frame`, wrap a `data.frame` on the vector

```
data.frame(summaryOut = as.character(methods('summary')), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

---

If we need to list all functions from a package

```
out <- data.frame(baseFns = ls('package:base'))
subset(out, grepl('(table|str|class|summary', baseFns))
```

Comment: Thanks and helpful. But actually that was an example. What if I want to extract all default functions?

Comment: @DevP  What do you meant by default functions

Comment: Like we also have ```str```, ```table``` etc

Comment: There is a summary.default, not clear about your question

Comment: @DevP If you want all the non-starred functions `grep("*", methods('summary'), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: methods('summary') will list all functions with summary. Similarly we have ```table```, ```str```, ```class``` etc functions right?

Comment: @DevP I updated the post.  May be that helps