# Write all function names to a csv file

Tags: r, package

I want to get a list of all functions from a package. Look at this function:

```
ly.str("package:zoo")
```

It gives detailed information about the functions, but when I write it to a .csv file it only gives header list and not all the description.

```
write.csv(ly.str("package:zoo"))
```

Is there any way to get all information?

Comment: What is `ly.str`?

Comment: You could just download the docs: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf

Comment: You can use `write.csv(as.character(ls.str("package:zoo")),"file_name.csv")`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392542/is-there-a-command-in-r-to-view-all-the-functions-present-in-a-package

Comment: Do you mean `lsf.str()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all functions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535247/how-to-find-all-functions-in-an-r-package), capture the output (`capture.output()`) and do some conversions to a data.frame/data.table and the save it as a .csv:

```
require(zoo)
require(data.table)
dt = data.table(lsf_str = capture.output(lsf.str('package:zoo')))
max_col = max(lengths(strsplit(dt$lsf_str, ':')))
dt[ , paste0('V', 1:max_col) := tstrsplit(lsf_str, ':') ]
setnames(dt, c('V1', 'V2'), c('fun_name', 'fun_arg'))
# write
write.csv(dt, file.path(tempdir(), 'functions.csv'))
fwrite(dt, file.path(tempdir(), 'functions.csv')) # from data.table
```

This is not perfect, but get's you started.