# Export all hidden functions from a package

Tags: r, namespaces, package

Is there a way to automatically import all hidden functions from a package, ie functions accessible only with `package:::fun` ?

Indeed I have brought some modifications to a given function which uses quite a lot of internal functions and I want to avoid retyping `package:::` everywhere.

I looked at `loadNamespace` base function but it does not attach the non exported ones.

Comment: Can you give some more background? Is, e.g., creating a branch of the package and building it with your modifications an option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I finally found sort of a hack using [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696158/find-all-functions-including-private-in-a-package) and `eval`:

```
# get all the function names of the given package "mypack"
r <- unclass(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("mypack"), all = T))

# filter weird names
r <- r[-grep("\\[", r)]
r <- r[-grep("<-", r)]

# create functions in the Global Env. with the same name
for(name in r) eval(parse(text=paste0(name, '<-mypack:::', name)))
```

I would have thought there were some prebuilt function to do this anyway.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. this is because of some wired names (don't know what these functions are), you should add some filtering, see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, it's very useful for some occasion for external packages used. Little addendum: to not launch one or both of `r <- r[-grep(, r)]` if they found nothing (`integer(0)`) else `r` return `character(empty)`, or replace by `r<-if (any(grep("\\[", r) )) r[-grep("\\[", r)] else r` and `r<-if (any(grep("<-", r) )) r[-grep("<-", r)] else r`

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but this is an insanely convoluted, poorly working hack for something that can be done in a single line of code: `list2env(as.list(asNamespace(pkgname), all.names = TRUE), envir = environment())`. However, there is virtually *no* use-case where indiscriminately dumping all package names into the current environment is a good idea.

Comment: You are right in theory for the use case, but I have one. I had installed a project with many calls directly to hidden functions because a package, from the same author of the project, was to be compiled with their hidden functions made public. But it was very difficult to recompile by hand. So I preferred to use their CRAN package...with their hidden functions. During my first installation, I copied the Theirpackage::: prefix everywhere with many risk of forgetting. With the solution of exporting everything, I don't forget anything. But yes your list2env() seems more powerful and simple.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think dumping non-exported names from a package into the current environment is *ever* a good idea:<sup>1</sup> there’s a reason why these functions are not exported, and at the point where you find yourself accessing them in bulk you should stop and rethink your approach.

Given your specific use-case (edit a function from a package that needs to use non-exported names internally), a better solution would be to assign the package namespace as the function’s environment:

```
the_edited_function = function (…) { … }
environment(the_edited_function) = asNamespace('the_package')
```

… of course it goes without saying that this is *also* a horrible hack and should rarely be necessary.

---

<sup>1</sup> It *can* be done with a single expression:

```
list2env(as.list(asNamespace('the_package'), all.names = TRUE), envir = environment())
```

… but, really, don’t do this.

Comment: Used now, but with only the functions `list2env(lapply(as.list(asNamespace("the_package"), all.names = TRUE), function(x) { if (is.function(x)) x }), envir = environment())`

Comment: @phili_b You can shorten this a bit by using `Filter(is.function, …)` instead of `lapply(…, function (x) { if (is.function(x)) x })`.