# Is it possible to list all available names which could be loaded via `.Call()`? Error in .Call("function")

Tags: c++, c, r, r-package

A very common question on StackOverflow with regards to C++/R or C/R package integration is regarding the error in `dyn.load()`, e.g.

```
> ## within R
> Error in .Call("function_c") : C symbol name "function_c" not in load table
```

whereby `function_c` is some function in C like

```
SEXP function_c() {
  Rprintf("Hello World!\n"); // manually changed
  return(R_NilValue);
}
```

This error come sup due to many types of mistakes, e.g. incorrect compliation, misnamed functions, the user didn't use `extern "C"` for Cpp code, etc.

Question: Is there any way to view all "available" objects which the user could load via `dyn.load()` after compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following? I'm not sure it covers *everything*, but it should be close:

```
# manipulate search() to get all loaded packages
loadedPkgs = grep('^package:', search(), value = TRUE)
loadedPkgs = gsub('package:', '', loadedPkgs, fixed = TRUE)
# add names here to make the results of lapply pretty
names(loadedPkgs) = loadedPkgs

allCRoutines = lapply(loadedPkgs, function(pkg) {
  # see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696158/
  pkg_env = asNamespace(pkg)
  # this works at a glance
  check_CRoutine = function(vname) {
    'CallRoutine' %in% attr(get(vname, envir = pkg_env), 'class')
  }
  names(which(sapply(ls(envir = pkg_env, all = TRUE), check_CRoutine)))
})
```

The object is a bit long, so I'll just show for one package:

```
allCRoutines[['utils']]
# $utils
#  [1] "C_crc64"         "C_flushconsole"  "C_menu"          "C_nsl"           "C_objectSize"    "C_octsize"       "C_processevents"
#  [8] "C_sockclose"     "C_sockconnect"   "C_socklisten"    "C_sockopen"      "C_sockread"      "C_sockwrite"
```

What I'm not sure of is that `check_CRoutine` catches everything we'd consider as relevant to your question. I'm also not sure this covers your main interest (whether these objects can succesfully be fed to `dyn.load`); perhaps the routines returned here could be passed to `dyn.load` with a `try` wrapper?

Comment: Thanks! The `loadedPkgs` idea was pretty clever. (The above could use mclapply for those trying to speed things up.) I see lots of `character(0)` in the list; these are loaded packages with no C routines?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang yes