# How to scan all function formals in a package for a particular parameter such as `na.rm`?

Tags: r, function, eval, r-package

I want to review the use of `na.rm` in the base packages initially, but the general idea would be to find any parameter in any packages.

### Packages

```
packages = (.packages());
```

### Functions in Packages

I don't know how reliable this is, as it was later throwing errors on `formals`

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696158/find-all-functions-including-private-in-a-package
functions.listFromPackage = function(pkg = "stats")
    {
    all     = ls( getNamespace(pkg),        all.names = TRUE); 
    # public has to be loaded ... 
    public  = ls( paste0("package:", pkg),  all.names = TRUE);
    private = setdiff(all, public);
    list("public" = public, "private" = private);
    }
```

### Formals

Since the list above gives me strings, I guess I have to parse so formals will like the input.

```
has.na = NULL;
## LOOP over fn.str in package
fn.obj = eval(parse(text=fn.str));
x = formals( fn.obj );
if(is.primitive(fn.obj)) { x = formals(args(fn.obj)); }
if("na.rm" %in% names(x) )
          {
            row = c(package, fn, x$na.rm);
            has.na = rbind(has.na, row);
          }
```

### Preliminary Results

```
> has.na
    [,1]      [,2]              [,3]   
row "stats"   "approx"          "TRUE" 
row "stats"   "approxfun"       "TRUE" 
row "stats"   "density.default" "FALSE"
row "stats"   "fivenum"         "TRUE" 
row "stats"   "heatmap"         "TRUE" 
row "stats"   "IQR"             "FALSE"
row "stats"   "mad"             "FALSE"
row "stats"   "median"          "FALSE"
row "stats"   "median.default"  "FALSE"
row "stats"   "medpolish"       "FALSE"
row "stats"   "sd"              "FALSE"
row "stats"   "var"             "FALSE"
row "methods" "Summary"         "FALSE"
row "base"    ".colMeans"       "FALSE"
row "base"    ".colSums"        "FALSE"
row "base"    ".rowMeans"       "FALSE"
row "base"    ".rowSums"        "FALSE"
row "base"    "all"             "FALSE"
row "base"    "any"             "FALSE"
```

It is throwing a lot of errors.

```
Warning messages:
1: In formals(fun) : argument is not a function

# for example fn.str = "p.adjust.methods"
Error in get(fun, mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  first argument has length > 1

# for example fn.str = "contrasts<-"
Error in parse(text = fn) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: contrasts<-
# obvious why `eval` fails here.  How to get the formals in a variadic way (as a list of strings?)
```

So I am thinking my collection of functions may be inaccurate?

## Question: how to write a function that captures all functions that use a parameter (with the default value) for a given set of package(s)?

### ==Accepted Solution==

The `match.fun()` was the key element of the solution.  I have my function loop over the GLOBAL `ls(all.names=TRUE)` for local functions, then I loop over a list of packages specified in the package call.

Here is the head/str of one result:

```
> head(df)
        pkg  fn.is         fn.name param.value
row   stats public          approx        TRUE
row.1 stats public       approxfun        TRUE
row.2 stats public density.default       FALSE
row.3 stats public         fivenum        TRUE
row.4 stats public         heatmap        TRUE
row.5 stats public             IQR       FALSE
> str(df)
'data.frame':   44 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ pkg        : chr  "stats" "stats" "stats" "stats" ...
 $ fn.is      : chr  "public" "public" "public" "public" ...
 $ fn.name    : chr  "approx" "approxfun" "density.default" "fivenum" ...
 $ param.value: chr  "TRUE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE" ...
 - attr(*, "param")= chr "na.rm"
 - attr(*, "packages")= chr [1:2] "stats" "base"
>
```

I intentionally did *NOT* cast to anything on the dataframe.  The `na.rm` example has unique: TRUE, FALSE, "" (listed as a function parameter without any default assigned). Post processing on the function can create `factors` and so on.

TODO:  allow for the parameter to be a vector, maybe `JSON.stringify` using jsonlite::FUNCTIONS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

functions in a package

```
x <- ls(getNamespace('stats'), all.names = TRUE)
y <- sapply(x, function(x) inherits(try(match.fun(x), silent = TRUE), 'try-error'))
f <- x[!y]
head(f)
# [1] ".checkMFClasses" ".getXlevels"     ".lm.fit"         ".MFclass"        ".nknots.smspl"   ".preformat.ts"
```

functions that have `na.rm` as an arg

```
z <- sapply(f, function(x) is.null(formals(match.fun(x))$na.rm))
head(f[!z])
# [1] "approx"          "approxfun"       "density.default" "fivenum"         "heatmap"         "IQR"
```

the default value of `na.rm` for each

```
head(sapply(f[!z], function(x) formals(match.fun(x))$na.rm))
# approx       approxfun density.default         fivenum         heatmap             IQR 
#   TRUE            TRUE           FALSE            TRUE            TRUE           FALSE
```

You could combine these into a single step

```
f <- function(package) {
  p <- ls(getNamespace(package), all.names = TRUE)
  y <- lapply(p, function(x) {
    mf <- try(match.fun(x), silent = TRUE)
    pr <- is.primitive(mf)
    
    if (inherits(mf, 'try-error') ||
        is.null(args(mf)) ||
        (pr && !is.logical(formals(args(mf))$na.rm)) ||
        (!is.logical(formals(mf)$na.rm)))
      NULL
    else {
      data.frame(
        package = package,
        'function' = x,
        na.rm = if (pr)
          formals(args(mf))$na.rm else formals(mf)$na.rm
      )
    }
  })
  
  do.call('rbind', y)
}

f('stats')
#    package       function. na.rm
# 1    stats          approx  TRUE
# 2    stats       approxfun  TRUE
# 3    stats density.default FALSE
# 4    stats         fivenum  TRUE
# 5    stats         heatmap  TRUE
# 6    stats             IQR FALSE
# 7    stats             mad FALSE
# 8    stats          median FALSE
# 9    stats  median.default FALSE
# 10   stats       medpolish FALSE
# 11   stats              sd FALSE
# 12   stats             var FALSE

f('methods')
#   package function. na.rm
# 1 methods   Summary FALSE

f('base')
#    package         function. na.rm
# 1     base         .colMeans FALSE
# 2     base          .colSums FALSE
# 3     base         .rowMeans FALSE
# 4     base          .rowSums FALSE
# 5     base          colMeans FALSE
# 6     base           colSums FALSE
# 7     base       is.unsorted FALSE
# 8     base      mean.default FALSE
# 9     base              pmax FALSE
# 10    base          pmax.int FALSE
# 11    base              pmin FALSE
# 12    base          pmin.int FALSE
# 13    base     range.default FALSE
# 14    base          rowMeans FALSE
# 15    base rowsum.data.frame FALSE
# 16    base    rowsum.default FALSE
# 17    base           rowSums FALSE
```

Comment: There it is `match.fun` is what I was missing.  Does `match.fun` take care of the primitive issue for `formals`; that is `if(is.primitive(fn.obj)) { x = formals(args(fn.obj)); }`

Comment: My solution just loops once [nested] over the data using `for` doing checks along the way.  Your `apply` techniques are certainly more VECTORIZED than what I am doing, but they may be looping more, I am not sure, but they certainly helped me understand what step I was missing.  I trap errors and warnings on the `match.fun()` and `formals` both regular and `args()` for primitives.  Thank you again for the `match.fun()` clue, that was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @mshaffer see edits for a single loop version

Comment: Looks good.  I would add `param="na.rm"` to the function `f` and replace `$na.rm` to `[[param]]` to make it fully variadic.  I cast the value as a character `as.character(f[[param]])` but may use JSON.stringify to allow for vectors (as an option in the function).  There are a few `na.rm` that are in the PARAMETERS without values, so `as.character` shows them as an empty string `""`

Comment: I did add the FACTORS and print an XTABS summary: ```df$pkg = as.factor(df$pkg);
  df$fn.is = as.factor(df$fn.is);
  df$param.value = as.factor(df$param.value);
 
 
 summary = xtabs(~pkg+param.value , df);
 
 print( summary );```